# Fragment inside a module library, not able call to application

Tags: android

When call the Fragment UI from module library to application, UI not able to find the id of xml layout showing as null.

How to call a library module with fragment, call inside a application.

Eg:

Application (com.example.app1)
library module (com.example.lib)

library module - contains with activity and fragment, only activity ui is showing from library module, not fragment ui is not working.

Comment: I cannot understand your question, may be adding some code may help

Comment: share some code